# How to pass an image buffer to an OpenCV Mat object?

Tags: c++, c, opencv3.0

I am currently programming with a PixeLINK USB3 machine vision camera along with OpenCV in C. I have had some success passing camera images in Mat format with the following code:

```
PXL_RETURN_CODE rc = PxLInitialize(0, &hCamera);
if (!API_SUCCESS(rc))
{
    printf("Error: Unable to initialize a camera. \n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

vector<U8> frameBuffer(3000 * 3000 * 2);
FRAME_DESC frameDesc;

    if (API_SUCCESS(PxLSetStreamState(hCamera, START_STREAM)))
{
    while (true)
    {
        frameDesc.uSize = sizeof(frameDesc);
        rc = GetNextFrame(hCamera, (U32)frameBuffer.size(), &frameBuffer[0], 
                          &frameDesc, 5);

        Mat image(2592, 2048, CV_8UC1);
        Mat imageCopy;

        // Where passing of image data occurs
        int k = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < 2048; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < 2592; col++)
            {
                image.at<uchar>(row, col) = frameBuffer[k];
                k++;
            }
        }...
```

As I mentioned this works, but it seems very sloppy. I have looked online but haven't found too much detail.

I have tried:

```
Mat image(2592, 2048, CV_8UC1, &frameBuffer, size_t step=AUTO_STEP);
```

as well as,

```
Mat image(2592, 2048, CV_8UC1, frameBuffer, size_t step=AUTO_STEP).
```

The former is the only one that compile successfully, and displays gibberish - I mean, it doesn't form an image.

Comment: The C tag here is not needed, you are using C++.  On point, does the byte order of the file you are processing match that of your dev environment?

Comment: Would you please elaborate little bit

Comment: Thank you Leonardo for the reformat. Looks much nicer. As for your question, I am running on the same computer as my dev environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried switching the `row` and `col` of your `Mat`?

You initialized your Mat with `row` = 2592, `col` = 2048,
but you're using switched `row` and `col` in your `for()` loop.

I think this code should work properly:

```
Mat image(2048, 2592, CV_8UC1, &frameBuffer[0]);
```

Or, if you're using C++11,

```
Mat image(2048, 2592, CV_8UC1, frameBuffer.data());
```

Comment: Thank you Suhyeon! The swapping of rows and columns worked! Sorry for making such an obvious mistake.